# QByteArray to Integer conversion produces incorrect results

Tags: c++, qt5, qbytearray

I'm trying to convert a byte array to integer:

```
QByteArray b = QByteArray::fromHex("00008000");
quint32 result = b[3];
result += b[2] << 8;
result += b[1] << 16;
result += b[0] << 24;
```

but I'm getting `4294934528` instead of `32768`. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) is an array of `char`s. Apparently, `char` on your platform is signed and 8-bit wide. Thus, your problem can be distilled to:

```
char c = 0x80;
quint32 = c << 8;
```

The standard mandates that:

> N4606 § 4.8 [conv.integral] / 3
>
> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is
>   implementation-defined.

In this case (as usual on 2's complement systems), `0x80` is mapped to `std::numeric_limits<char>::min()` == `-128`, which is only logical because they share the same underlying bit pattern.

Now, `-128 << 8` is defined as -128 * 2<sup>8</sup>, which is -32768.

Finally, conversion from `-32768` to 32 bit unsigned integer is well defined and yields `4294934528`

Comment: I ended up using `QDataStream` for the conversion. In-case anyone is interested.